# Android video calls using android's sip

Tags: android, video-streaming, sip

I want to develop a program for a video calls in android. I thought of using the built in sip that introduced in android 2.3.3. But how can I initiate the video calls? I see that it is not supported.

Comment: What was the answer for your question? Android in-built SIP support video call or not? if yes then how? Plz I am looking for the same for long time.

Comment: This question was asked 2 years ago. I dont know what happened in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the generic Android SIP stack supports video.

Taken from: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

> If you want to create generic SIP connections (such as for video calls
>   or other), you can create a SIP connection from the [`SipManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html),
>   using [`open()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#open%28android.net.sip.SipProfile%29). If you only want to create audio SIP calls,
>   though, you should use the [`SipAudioCall`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html) class, as described
>   above.

If you don't mind using external SIP stacks, check out this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1NHEsXFEns

which uses [Jain-SIP](http://java.net/projects/jain-sip/).

**EDIT**: As of late, this project seems to be the leader in the native Android SIP space:

https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/ - open source, and they offer everything you need to make voice and video calls.

Comment: No. If you read it again you will see that it says "generic SIP connections". ie only connection without RTP.

Comment: So you need to use RTP? Because the generic SIP can transport video: _While there's a helper class for audio calls, you can use the `open()` and `close()` methods of the `SipManager` class to initiate other types of SIP communication, **like text or video sessions**. You'll have to provide the bi-directional streaming, though._ explained here: http://www.developer.com/ws/getting-started-with-sip-in-android.html as well

Comment: It says **You'll have to provide the bi-directional streaming, though.** ie "you can do it on your own, but we don't provide it yet.