# Video Call through SIP in Android

Tags: android, sip

I am beginner in Android and working on an application which could make video call over IP using SIP. I searched about it a lot on Google and also on StackOverflow and all I got is that I would need some Native Library, about which I don't have so much knowledge.

I looked after Linphone and Csipsimple and IMSdroid but didn't get anything (means I don't need the working application, I just want to know how they work).

Using inbuild SIP stack in Android, I am able to make Audio Calls but don't know how to do this with Video.

Is there any simple way to do this?

So, If there is any suggestion for me, plz tell me..

Thanks in Advance. I am looking for some positive responses. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android video calls using android's sip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960312/android-video-calls-using-androids-sip)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from my answer here: [Android video calls using android's sip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960312/android-video-calls-using-androids-sip/)

I believe the generic Android SIP stack supports video...

Taken from: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

If you want to create generic SIP connections (such as for video calls or other), you can create a SIP connection from the [`SipManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html), using [`open()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#open%28android.net.sip.SipProfile%29). If you only want to create audio SIP calls, though, you should use the [`SipAudioCall`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html) class, as described above.

and, if you want or don't mind using external libraries/SIP stacks, check out this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1NHEsXFEns

which uses [Jain-SIP](http://java.net/projects/jain-sip/) should help!

**EDIT**: As of late, this project seems to be the leader in the native Android SIP space:

https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/ .. open source and they offer everything you need to make voice and video calls.