# video call using Session Initiation Protocol android

Tags: android, video-streaming, sip, real-time-data

Is it possible to make video call using Session Initiation Protocol in android.

I found SipAudioCall for audio calling but did not find any similar class for video calling.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however video streaming is not implemented.
Consider using one of [third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511372/voip-library-for-android/13511858#13511858).

See also:

[Android video calls using android's sip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960312/android-video-calls-using-androids-sip/)

[Video Call through SIP in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747532/video-call-through-sip-in-android)